# 「一層」 「一段」 「なおさら」 「ぐっと」 「めっきり」

Tags: word-choice

「一層」と「一段」と「なおさら」と「ぐっと」と「めっきり」の違いを教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23041/what-is-the-difference-between-%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%A4-%E4%B8%80%E6%AE%B5%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%A4 この文章に一層と一段の違いは説明されていますね。この例文にあてはめると、ぐっといいパソコン、めっきりいいパソコンは少し店員に尋ねるのには抽象的になりますね。それに対して、一層いいパソコン、一段いいパソコン、尚更いいパソコンは、そのパソコンもいいけど、さらに一つ上以上のレベルのパソコンを紹介してもらうのにより具体的で比較的ふさわしい表現だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Related: [What is the difference between 一層, 一段と and より一層?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23041/what-is-the-difference-between-%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%A4-%E4%B8%80%E6%AE%B5%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%B1%A4)

一段、一層 are already explained in this text a little bit. Now, let me use them in the sentence of よいパソコン In the text. I suppose that using ぐっといいパソコン、めっきりいいパソコン to shop clerk is abstract.They might wonder how much better PCs you want to have a look. On the other hand, 一層いいパソコン、一段いいパソ‌​コン、尚更いいパソコン are more concrete and it implies that you want to have a look at PCs which is better than you are checking now by one rank better or couple of ranks better PCs. So, it sounds more specific.